# restart apache service automatically using cron at 22:51 Daily

Tags: apache, nginx

I have a CentOs7.8 Setup for my server. I want to run a cron job everyday specifically at 22:51

please tell me how can i do that, i am facing an unknown error everyday as my server show me 502 bad gateway on exact 22:51, apache stops working everyday, i don't know why.

Comment: This started after i enable nginx and because of the server load i cannot remove it.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. You should really figure out why your server is going down at 22:51. Is this hosted with someone or personal machine? To answer your question though see `https://crontab.guru/#51_22_*_*_*`. https://crontab.guru/#51_22_%2A_%2A_%2A

Comment: it is hosted with ovh